SignalR send from Web API, but not received in Angular
I have a Web API that receives a response from payment bank gateway and I want to send this response to my Angular app through SignalR.
But Angular does not receive it, and redirect to my Web API Uri.
await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", result.Data);            

My hub:
public class MyHub : Hub
{
     public async Task SendMessage(string message)
     {
         try
         {
             await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
         }
     }
}


In program.cs:

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("EnableCors",
        builder => builder
                //.SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)
                 .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
               //.SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                //.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowCredentials()
                .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()
    //.Build()
    );
});

app.UseCors("EnableCors");

My Angular code:
@Output() onSignalRMessage: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.startConnection();
    this.receiveMessage();
}

public startConnection = () => {
    console.log('Starting connection...');
    this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl('http://localhost:5033/myHub'
        , {      
          accessTokenFactory: () => localStorage.getItem('tax-cookie')
        })
      .build();
   
    this.hubConnection.start()
      .then(() => console.log('Connection started'))
      .catch(err => console.log('Error while starting connection: ' + err));
}

receiveMessage = () => {

    this.hubConnection.on('ReceiveMessage', (message: string) => {
      console.log('receiveMessage: ' + message);

      this.paymentStatusSubject.next(message);
      this.onSignalRMessage.emit(this.paymentStatusSubject);
    });
}

public addTransferChartDataListener() {
    this.hubConnection.on('ReceiveMessage', (data) => {
      console.log('ReceiveMessage: ' + data);
    });
  }
}

app.component.ts :
export class AppComponent {
 
  private hubConnection: signalR.HubConnection;
  constructor(
    private signalRService: SignalRService,
    private router: Router
  ) { }
  public messages = [];
  ngOnInit() {
   this.signalRService.onSignalRMessage.subscribe((data) => {
     
        this.messages.push(data);
         console.log('receiveMessage: ' + this.messages[0]);
      })
    }

It redirects to Web API uri and does not run Angular!
Can anyone help me?

What does mean "It redirects to Web API uri and does not run Angular!"? When does it redirect? How? I don't see an issue in the code you provided, does it connect to the hub?

dear Adrian, yes , angular connected to my hub, but when webApi send a signalR message, my browser not show angular app(not return to my angular app), and it stays  on the webApi Uri(http://localhost:5033/Account/payment-call-back/...)

So to clarify, you're redirecting the user to some payment gateway, then the gateway redirects the user to your webapi (/Account/payment-call-back..) and then you expect to render here the angular app, but the user is stuck on webapi uri? If so, you have to make a redirect to the app in your webapi route, it's not an issue related to the angular. I guess you should redirect from webapi to the angular app's specific route, which has this signalR logic. If you have a response that you want to show to the user already in the callback route, you can pass data to angular by queryparams for example.

Yes, you got it right , So that means I should not use the signalR? and only redirect to angular rout? like this :                     return Redirect(string.Format("http://localhost:4200/#/finishPackagePayment?result={0}", result.Data));  My problem is that if I use this, even though I have added Cors in the program.cs,I have a problem Cors Error. I feel it is because I am redirecting from the server side to the client

There are multiple ways you can solve the issue, but yes, in my opinion, passing some result id or something (as far as the data is not sensitive!) in query parameters is simplest and most reliable solution. CORS error is related to your configuration, from your comments I can see that your server uses port 5033 and your client 4200, you have to configure CORS on your server side to allow using client on different origin, which is localhost:4200. You can read how to configure CORS in aspnetcore in the documentation

(2) For the simplicity of the solution, you can go with the default policy section in the cors doucmentation

I agree with Adrian and we require a redirection so that the payment gateway response could be resend to Angular app. About the CORS error, I found a similar issue here. By the way, is it possible to ask the payment gateway to redirect to angular app directly and let the client app to call web api?

dear Adrian,Redirect(string.Format("http://localhost:4200/#/finishPackagePayment?result={0}", result.Data)); ,but when run layout of angular,Even though it managed the Cors issue in program.cs(As you can see above),it still gives a cors error when redirected! Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5033/Account/get-AllPaymentTransaction' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:5033' that is not equal to the supplied origin.

dear Tiny, thank's a lot , I will definitely ask them if it is possible?

dear tiny , I do not understand the example of Cors you sent, i handled Cors in program.cs included in my question

my second Cors error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): HttpErrorResponse: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"status":0,"statusText":"Unknown Error","url":"http://localhost:5033/Account/get-AllPaymentTransaction","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for http://localhost:5033/Account/get-AllPaymentTransaction: 0 Unknown Error","error":{"isTrusted":true}}

Could you please change to use "allow all" cors policy to test if it worked or not? using .AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod()

No, it didn't work with this code either. And it gives the same Cors error :(

could you pls let me know whether you delete .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()?

I find a desription that SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains and WithOrigins both relate to configuring which origins can access resources, they cannot be used together in a straightforward manner because they target different approaches for specifying allowed origins, WithOrigins is used for specifying explicit, full origin URIs, while SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains allows all subdomains of a particular domain, so that I asked whether you delete SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains.
